# How to fix an error of type changing in Power BI?

Tags: excel, powerbi-desktop

I have a dataset in Excel composed of 3 columns : date, GDP, and percentage of chane in GDP. I uploaded the dataset on Power BI and the data type of GDP and % of change in GDP are marked as text and when I try to convert them to decimal an error occurs. 
It usually works.

Comment: There's possibly some entry in the column that cannot be converted to decimal.  What, exactly, is the error?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld When I change the data type all values are converted to error

Comment: If you click on **error**, it should open a window that tells you what the problem is